# how can I initialize a 3rd party module within my .forRoot() in angular

Tags: angular, toastr, angular-toastr

I am building an internal library for our projects, using Angular 6+.
I am using the `.forRoot()` approach to register global services as documented.

My library will be using `ngx-toastr` to provide notifications. As I don't want each project to deal directly with all the options of `ngx-toastr`, I am abstracting most of it behind a `notifications` service.

The way `ngx-toastr` works, you can set global options by passing those global options to `ToastrModule.forRoot()`.

**how can I configure `ToastrModule` as part of my own `forRoot()`?**

It's clearly a bad idea to add any code inside the `.forRoot()`, but is the right way to initialize it directly in my `@NgModule()`? like this:

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [ToastrModule.forRoot(/* options go here? */)],
    declarations: [],
    exports: []
})
export class ToolsCoreModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: ToolsCoreModule,
            providers: [],
        };
    }
}
```

How would this interact if someone on the team decides to also call `ToastrModule.forRoot()` within their own module initialization?

Answer (score 2):

As @migh mentioned, `forRoot()` should only be called by `AppModule`, but a nested `forRoot()` within a `forRoot()` provider is still called by the `AppModule`, isn't it?

So you can do the following

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [],
    declarations: [],
    exports: [ToastrModule]
})
export class ToolsCoreModule {
    static forRoot(/* your options */): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: ToolsCoreModule,
            providers: [...ToastrModule.forRoot(/* toastr options */).providers],
        };
    }
}
```

> How would this interact if someone on the team decides to also call `ToastrModule.forRoot()` within their own module initialization?

You'll may get a runtime error or a strange behavior.

To avoid the 'strange behavior', you should also add this pattern to your module that prevents double registration:

```js
constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule?: ToolsCoreModule)
{
    if (parentModule)
    {
        throw new Error(
            "ToolsCoreModule is already loaded. Import it in the AppModule only!");
    }
}
```

That pattern is from the official documentation:
https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#prevent-reimport-of-the-greetingmodule

Answer (score 1):

The root module that exports your notifications service via `providers` should be the only one that uses `ToastrModule.forRoot()` in an `imports` declaration.

The `forRoot()` call is a convention and not something enforced by the framework. Others shouldn't be calling this when defining their NgModules if it has already been called higher up.

[As mentioned in the Angular documentation:](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-is-the-forroot-method)

> Only call and import a `.forRoot()` result in the root application module, `AppModule`. Importing it in any other module, particularly in a lazy-loaded module, is contrary to the intent and will likely produce a runtime error.
>
> ...
>
> `forRoot()` and `forChild()` are conventional names for methods that configure services in root and feature modules respectively.

If your global configuration for `ToastrModule` never changes, I don't think there's anything wrong doing it the way you've questioned in your snippet.

However, if the configuration might change depending on consumers of `ToolsCoreModule`, you shouldn't be calling `forRoot()` for each different configuration, as that's wrong by convention. In this case, you could consider creating wrappers around the third argument of toast calls to pass common configuration (e.g. `this.toastrService.error(msg, title, config)`).